# How to access IFC mapping file programmatically?

Tags: c#, revit-api, revit, ifc

Does Revit API provide a way to access IFC mapping file programmatically?

I guess I can navigate to the file using the standard methods that manipulate files on a file system, but I was wondering if Revit has a way to it easier.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any additional support for this from Revit or its API.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look through the Autodesk IFC exporter code on GitHub? I'd imagine they must be accessing the mapping in there somehow.

`ExporterUtil.GetExportType()` looks a good place to start:

https://github.com/Autodesk/revit-ifc/blob/2810c479e27819da97656759a1dda28cbdde0538/Source/Revit.IFC.Export/Utility/ExporterUtil.cs#L1433

Comment: Thanks for pointing out to this repo, i wasn't aware of it. I will need some time to understand what it is for, how to run it and how to use it, before i can tell whether it is what i'm looking for or not.